# rotation and radians in XNA, Enemy Ai corrections

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, artificial-intelligence

ive been having trouble with my mob AI

it works to a point, except it does the opposite of what i want, meaning it turns 180Degrees in the wrong direction

```
        Target = playerST.Posistion;
        Vector2 trivial;
        trivial.X = Posistion.X - Target.X;
        trivial.Y = Posistion.Y - Target.Y;
        instant = ((float)Math.Atan2(trivial.Y, trivial.X)) + 3.141592f;
```

this tells me where my target is  and calculates the numbers i need to rotate to

its in radians the plus 3.1etc is  like 180 degrees,  as calculating it this way gives me either a minumum of -3.141 or a maximum of 
3.141 but the rotations of the enemy is done in 0 to 6.28 adding the 3.141 makes instant =  in the range of the enemies rotation  instead of under it by 3.141

anyway this is the part i get stuck at... the actual rotation

```
        // irrelevant
                if (attack == true)
            {

                Vector2 modelVelocityAdd = Vector2.Zero;

                modelVelocityAdd.Y = -(float)Math.Sin(rotation);
                modelVelocityAdd.X = -(float)Math.Cos(rotation);

                modelVelocityAdd *= (0.00002f * speed);
                if ((((rotation) + 0.2f)) < instant && (rotation - 0.2f) > instant)
                {
                    modelVelocity += modelVelocityAdd;
                }
        // not so irrelvant and needs fixing!
                if (instant < rotation )
                    {
                         rotation -= rotationspeed / 2000;
                    }
                else if (rotation < instant)
                    {
                         rotation += rotationspeed / 2000;
                    }
```

so my problem is how  do i stop it from rotating 180 degrees in the wrong direction and actually get it to face the player instead of facing the exact opposite

i cant simply,do what is below because the ship gets trapped and goes back and forth  between say 5 degrees and minus 5 degrees

```
            if (instant < rotation )
                    {
                         rotation += rotationspeed / 2000;
                    }
                else if (rotation < instant)
                    {
                         rotation -= rotationspeed / 2000;
                    }
```

thanks for any help

Comment: not being smart but can't you just reverse the polarity? By this I mean swap your rotationspeed -= and +=

Comment: Take a look at [Chapter 6](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/) of The Nature of Code, specifically, Example 6.1.

Comment: of course i thought of that ... but if i do that... the enemy ship get stuck and it sort of goes like this 
goes to +10 Degrees reaches  certain point goes back to minus 10 back and forth like that... so i cant simple swap them

Comment: @QuantumArchi - I believe the going back and forth is an indication it is working.  You need to have a way for it to not change at all --- which you don't have.

Comment: @Hogan -yes but its going back and forth not directed at the target  its going back and forth 0

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
           if (instant < rotation )
                {
                     rotation += rotationspeed / 2000;
                }
            else if (rotation < instant)
                {
                     rotation -= rotationspeed / 2000;
                }
```

try

```
rotation = Math.Lerp(rotation, instant, 0.1);
```

The 0.1 controls the rotation "speed". Using lerp makes the movement more natrual and will fix the problem of the angle oscillating between positive and negative.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out,

```
    trivial.X = Posistion.X - Target.X;
    trivial.Y = Posistion.Y - Target.Y;
```

are wrong it need to be

```
    trivial.X = Target.X -Posistion.X  ;
        trivial.Y = Target.Y - Posistion.Y ;
```

thank you without your help i never would of noticed :D